# Redirecting to a page and scrolling to a specific div

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I redirect to following URL using Zend Framework?

```
http://hms.localhost.com/booking/room#availableResults
```

I can't use Java Script. This needs to be done using Zend Framework Controller helpers such as rediretor();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a controller:

```
$this->_redirect('/booking/room#availableResults');
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok via Zend, First hit @ Google:

The gotoRoute() method doesn't support hashes, but you can accomplish this by using the url action helper to construct the url based on your route, and then concatenate your hash to it. Then call the redirector's gotoUrl method:

```
$url = $this->_helper->url->url(array('module' => 'blog',
'controller' => 'documentation', 'action' => 'tags'));
 $url .= "#add";
$this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl($url);
```

Comment: I need to do this using a controller in Zend Framework...I can't use javascript for this..

Comment: Take a look again @ my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

set your div id as availableResults

```
<div id="availableResults">
...
..
..
```

for redirecting in codeigniter

```
$url = 'http://hms.localhost.com/booking/room#availableResults';
redirect($url);
```

Comment: The div id is all ready set in the View script....I need to redirect from my controller...